# parallel computing support in enthought python

Tags: python, enthought

Does Enthought Canopy support parallel code execution on CPU using perhaps openMPI or on GPU using openCV or CUDA

I am looking into switching from C++ to python as i want to make GUI for my parallel code.

Is this a good idea. Does python support parallel computation?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Python does support this. There are three layers to processes with Python:

- `subprocess`: which simply starts a process within the same thread
- `threading`: which starts a new thread and leaves the old on alone. There are some frequent stories that this not necessarily leads to better performance.
- `multiprocessing`: which is what you are after

[Here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing) is an intro to parallel processing on Python.

The official docs for the multiprocessing are [here](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html).

The ever so useful discussions on the [Python Module of the Week](http://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html) are also worth a look.

Edit:

The python libraries mentioned by HT @jonathan are likely to be:

Cuda:
http://mathema.tician.de/software/pycuda

OpenCV:
http://code.google.com/p/pyopencv/

There is a nice tutorial for this [here](http://www.neuroforge.co.uk/index.php/getting-started-with-python-a-opencv).

And Message Passing Interface: 
http://mpi4py.scipy.org/docs/usrman/intro.html

Comment: Enthought Canopy does not include openMPI, openCV, or CUDA, but you can install any of these into it, as you could into most other CPython distributions.

Comment: @jonathan could you tell which library to install in enthought?

Comment: There is nothing different about Enthought Python. Install whichever library meets the needs of your project.